# libGL error: failed to load driver swrast in docker container

Tags: docker, pyqt, docker-compose, dockerfile, nvidia

I have a docker container from which I am trying to run a pyqt app. Everything works well except a chunk of the GUI is not able to render. The docker logs throw this out:

```
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error: GLXBadContext 169
 Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
 Minor opcode: 6 (Unknown request)
 Resource id:  0x6400003
X Error: BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation) 2
 Extension:    154 (Uknown extension)
 Minor opcode: 3 (Unknown request)
 Resource id:  0x0
...
QGLContext::makeCurrent(): Failed.
```

In my Dockerfile, I tried installing pretty much all the packages I could find that might be related, including `mesa-utils`.

In terms of the docker-compose file, here's what it looks like:

```
version: '2'
    services:
    gui:
        build: .
        volumes:
        - .:/usr/src
        - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
        command: /bin/bash -c "python start.py"
        environment:
        - DISPLAY=unix$DISPLAY
        - QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1
        devices:
        - "/dev/snd:/dev/snd"
        - "/dev/dri:/dev/dri"
        privileged: true
```

Any ideas what I might be missing?

Comment: Fun one. I suspect that the issue is that the kernel may not have the drivers it needs. I've personally never tried to get docker to work in a gui environment, so it's just speculation on my part. have you confirmed that the host kernel has a video driver loaded? IIRC, swarst is for software rendering, which means that it's not using the hardware GPU.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Figured it out. I had to build the `gui` with hardware accelerated OpenGL support. Theres a repo (https://github.com/gklingler/docker3d) that contains docker images with nvidia or other graphics drivers support.

The other catch was, it didn't work for me unless the host and the container had the **exact** same driver. In order to resolve this, you can run the following shell script if you're running on linux:

```
#!/bin/bash
version="$(glxinfo | grep "OpenGL version string" | rev | cut -d" " -f1 | rev)"
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/"$version"/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-"$version".run
mv NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-"$version".run NVIDIA-DRIVER.run
```

Comment: To actually install the driver run: `sudo ./NVIDIA-DRIVER.run -a -N --ui=none --no-kernel-module`